# Spring boot: Doesn't open jsp files

Tags: java, maven, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm developing simple Spring Boot MVC application. Althought I have read many answers on SO I still can't fix Spring Boot not finding my .jsp files - it displays whitelabel error page.

Project Structure:
[image: Project structure.]

1. pom.xml

   ```
       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
           <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
           <groupId>com.learnbook</groupId>
           <artifactId>learnbook</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <packaging>war</packaging>
           <name>LearnBook</name>
           <description>We want to make the best courses in the market </description>

           <parent>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
               <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
           </parent>

       <dependencies>

               <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                   <version>1.2</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                   <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                   <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
               </dependency>

               <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                   <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
               </dependency>

               <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                   <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                   <scope>runtime</scope>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                   <scope>provided</scope>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                   <scope>test</scope>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                   <version>1.3.1</version>    
               </dependency>

               <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                   <version>2.4</version>
               </dependency>

                <dependency>
                   <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
                   <artifactId>cloudinary-http44</artifactId>
                   <version>1.4.6</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
                   <artifactId>cloudinary-taglib</artifactId>
                   <version>1.4.6</version>
               </dependency>

           </dependencies>

           <build>
               <plugins>
                   <plugin>
                       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   </plugin>
               </plugins>
           </build>


           <properties>
               <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
               <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
               <java.version>1.8</java.version>
           </properties>
       </project>
   ```

2.LearnBookApplication.java

```
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "net.learnbook.repository")
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class LearnBookApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(LearnBookApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.main")
        public DataSource siteDataSourceBean() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean siteEntityManagerFactoryBean(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            return builder.dataSource(siteDataSourceBean()).packages("net.learnbook.model").persistenceUnit("learnbookPU")
                    .build();
        }

    }
```

3.ServletInitializer.java

```
    public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(LearnBookApplication.class);
        }
    }
```

4. web.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
     <display-name>learnbook</display-name>
     <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>
   </web-app>
   ```
5. application.properties

   ```
   spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
   spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
   security.basic.enabled=false

   datasource.main.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/learnbook?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
   datasource.main.username:root
   datasource.main.password:root
   datasource.main.driverClassName:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

   spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto:create-drop
   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
   spring.jpa.show-sql=true
   ```
6. Controller

   ```
   @Controller
   public class ViewController {

       @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = { RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST}, name = "home_index")
       public String index() {
           return "index";
       }

   }'
   ```

Comment: suppose you follow this [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp).

Answer (score 0):

**FYI**

***From Spring boot Documentation:***

> JSPs should be avoided if possible, there are several known
>   limitations when using them with embedded servlet containers. You can
>   take further reading here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines

I believe that this means if you still want to use JSP pages, then you'll have to get rid of the embedded tomcat.